# Running code in one thread is slower than running the code in main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I'm testing running double calculations in a thread and I got this strange result. Running the calculations in the main thread takes almost half the time than running it in a separate thread and calling join in the main thread. If it's a single thread there shouldn't be a big difference from just running the function. Am I doing something wrong?

The cpu is Intel Xeon E-2136 limited at 4.1GHz to have the same boost frequency in independent of how many cores are running.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TEST_ITERATIONS 1000*1000*1000

void *testNN(void *dummy) {
  volatile double x;
  for (int i = 0; i < TEST_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
    x = rand();
    x *= rand();
  }
  return nullptr;
}

int main(){
    time_t start = time(nullptr);

    { // for future to join thread

      testNN(nullptr); // 12s

//      pthread_t thread_id;
//      pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, testNN, nullptr);
//      pthread_join(thread_id, NULL); //27s

      std::future<void *> f[12];
//      f[0] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);   // 27s
      // for multithreaded testing:
//    f[1] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[2] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[3] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[4] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[5] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[6] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[7] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[8] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[9] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[10] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);
//    f[11] = std::async(std::launch::async, testNN, nullptr);

    }

    time_t runTime = time(nullptr);
    runTime -= start;

    printf("calc done in %lds (%ld calc/s)\n", runTime, TEST_ITERATIONS / runTime);

}
```

I compile with

```
# g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp  -o test -lpthread
```

and results for function call, pthread and std::async respectively:

```
# time ./test
calc done in 12s (83333333 calc/s)

real    0m12.073s
user    0m12.070s
sys     0m0.003s

# time ./test
calc done in 27s (37037037 calc/s)

real    0m26.741s
user    0m26.738s
sys     0m0.004s

# time ./test
calc done in 27s (37037037 calc/s)

real    0m26.788s
user    0m26.785s
sys     0m0.003s
```

P.S. I'm still not sure if I want to use C++11. I used C++11 just to test if there is going to be a difference between plain phread and std::async.

**Update:** here is an easier to test version with less chance for mistake:

https://pastecode.io/s/ov4ifgy5

Comment: starting threads cost time too. So you need enough work to offset that startup time, and the work must be distributable over multiple threads. (Ideally with as little synchronization between the threads as possible)

Comment: Please don't tag C++ code with C tag.

Comment: Sorry, i removed it. Even though pthreads implementation is pure C. I'm just testing different implementations.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Starting a thread can never cost 15 seconds. I intentionally set the number of calculations to be much higher than start thread cost

Comment: can we see the testNN function? How are the threads synchronized? Do they share cache lines? Do you use mutexes? If they all do the same work then 27s/12threads = 2.7s is a lot faster compared to the single threaded call

Comment: @SoulKa: OP has already posted the definition of the `testNN` function.

Comment: @SoulKa I'm not discussing the multithread testing here. I want to know about the difference between *one* thread and not using threads

Comment: Sorry I missed that part on top. Try running it with 6 threads and look at the results! 12 Hypercores for such a tiny function are most likely not run completely in parallel

Comment: measuring performance of unoptimised code is generally a waste of time. Enable optimisations and test again. `std::async` and `std::thread` both use a lot of templated code which perform poorly without optimisations to inline functions

Comment: @SoulKa Yes, HT give almost no benefit for a funtion with not much code variety. But again - I'm talking about single thread tests only. the 12 threads are commented and not used in these tests

Comment: Side note: The function [`rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) is not guaranteed to be thread-safe. Therefore, your multithreaded test with 12 worker threads has a bug. You may want to consider using [`std::mt19937_64`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) instead.However, this is not the reason for your problem, because you are only asking about the test with 1 worker thread.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks. That was helpful. I'll research using rand_r or *rand_48_r.

Comment: @AlanBirtles using -O3 gives the same result. Result is:  main thread does the job for 11s, separate thread time is 26s - again more than double.

Comment: @NickSoft: You are commenting out the line `testNN(nullptr);` in your second and third test, aren't you? If you forget to do this, this would explain the test results.

Comment: Instead of answering your question inside the question itself, I believe it would be more appropriate to post an answer to your question. You may want to read this: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Well I was about to accept this other guy's question, but he deleted it.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel The question is still open to me: why `rand` is much slower in another thread? An update is justified as long as this is not answered. I can also reproduce the problem on another Intel Xeon processor, so it is not a mistake done during the benchmark (2x slower when `rand` is called from another thread than the main one).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: Yes, I am still puzzled by the benchmark results, too. It would probably be helpful if you and the OP provided more information about which platform (compiler, C runtime library (e.g. glibc) and operating system) you are using, as I am unable to reproduce the benchmark results on my platform system (Visual Studio on Microsoft Windows).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: You did add a comment in front of the line `testNN(nullptr);` when removing the comment in front of the lines that create a second thread, didn't you? If you did not, then that would explain why it takes double the amount of time.

Comment: CentOS 7,  GCC 4.8.5, exact same results reproduced on a raspberry pi with ubuntu 20.04.1 64-bit gcc version 9.4.0 (well exact same - I mean double the time in thread. Obviously different cpu - different times)

Comment: Well at least I thought I was able to reproduce it. Just tried again on raspberry pi - same time for the 3 tests, Quad core celeron J4115 with RoclyLinux 9, gcc-11.2.1 - same results for the 3 tests, retested on CentOS 7 again - still double the time within new thread. I even changed the code to not be possible to run two of the tests by mistake: https://pastecode.io/s/h688199d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AndreasWenzel I found out rand() is causing the slow down. In theory it shouldn't be a problem when only one thread is running (or at least no other thread is calling rand). Replacing rand() with rand_r() fixes the problem and even brings down the time to 8s for the same amount of work. Here is the test function:

```
void *testNN(void *dummy) {
  volatile double x;
  unsigned int seed = (unsigned int) time(nullptr);


  for (long i = 0; i < TEST_ITERATIONS; ++i) {
    x = rand_r(&seed);
    x *= rand_r(&seed);
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

I know **seeding like this is not ideal** - starting 12 threads will most likely seed all the threads with the same number, but that's just a test. I'll most likely have more complex seed function.